# OpenVPN Clients cannot see subnet behind client, but server can?

Tags: routing, openvpn, tomato

So, I have a rather unusual network setup, in which:

- I have a server (Let's call it `150.1.1.1` for example)
- This server runs a OpenVPN server (IP `10.10.4.1` with the DHCP Range `10.10.4.0/24`)
- I have an internal router (internal IP of `10.10.5.1`, with the DHCP range `10.10.5.0/24`) running Advanced Tomato
- This Router is a client of the VPN (with IP `10.10.4.3`)
- I have a handful of clients inside my LAN (`10.10.5.x`) such as a NAS and a Media server, these have IPs inside the DHCP range of the router (`10.10.5.54` for example)

Currently, I am able to, from the OpenVPN server, ping and connect to any device inside the `10.10.5.x` network, and vice versa.
I am however, not able to connect from any other device that connects to my OpenVPN server (whilst at work, at uni, etc) to any device inside the `10.10.5.x` range, i'm happy to provide any extra configs you'd find necessary. but currently I have:
**`/etc/openvpn/server.conf`**

```
port 636
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.10.4.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.10.5.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.4.3
push "route 10.10.5.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "remote-gateway 150.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 0
```

**`/etc/openvpn/ccd/routerclient`**

```
iroute 10.10.5.0 255.255.255.0
```

**`/etc/openvpn/client-configs/routerclient.ovpn`**

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 150.1.1.1 636
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
key-direction 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
verb 3
<ca>
SNIP
</ca>
<cert>
SNIP
</cert>
<key>
SNIP
</key>
<tls-auth>
SNIP
</tls-auth>
```